# renumbering a ID field

Tags: filemaker

Very new to Filemaker. Using Filemaker 11 pro.

I was wondering if it was possible to renumber an ID field column after doing an insert new record in between records?  Maybe using a script trigger?

thanks

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea. Can you explain your overall objective that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the Negative! Even though i explained i was very new to FileMaker, you give me a negative and not a comment as to why?

Comment: It wasn't a flame, it was an attempt to see if there was a better solution to your problem. As you point out, you are very new to FileMaker, so you may be trying to solve the wrong problem. If my intent had been to be negative, I would have down-voted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jesse that renumbering a record's unique ID/Index doesn't sound like a good idea and more information or an example of what you're trying to do would help.

If you simply want to display the Record Number, you could create an unstored calculation field with the calculation "Get ( RecordNumber )".  This should always display which record, of the found set, is being displayed.  FileMaker's definition is available here: http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref2.32.55.html

If, on the other hand, you're trying to make a unique sort order for the records being shown, it is best to do this by creating a new SortIndex numeric field.  (You'd need to make certain that the layout that you're displaying was always sorted by the SortIndex field which can be done using layout script triggers and, possibly, overriding the Sort menu commands using Custom Menus.)

One method to consider would be overriding the New Record command using Custom Menus.  When New Record is selected you might route it to a script which does something like this:

1. Get the current SortIndex value
2. Get the value of the SortIndex for the next record (by creating a self-join which shows records where the SortIndex > the SortIndex of the table occurrence your view is based on)
3. Place the average of those two values in a $variable
4. Create a new record and set its SortIndex to $variable

Comment: Note that to override the menu you'll need FileMaker Pro Advanced.

Comment: Unfortunately when Jesse's answer was deleted we also lost the comment about what @Shane was trying to do.  Shane, maybe you can modify the original question to include an example?  From what I recall the Title of the record is based on the ID of the record, which is why you want to modify the ID.  The problem that we see is if the ID is used to relate the record to any other table then you lose the connection to the proper record. To work around this you could create a TitleID field which is, initially, the same as your ID field and then change the Title to be based on the TitleID.